# Modifying values inside an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

Let's say have an array of objects:

```
let A = [
   {
    id: 1,
    item: 'item 1',
    qty: 23,
    unitPrice: 10;
    totalAmount: qty*price,
   },
   {
    id: 2,
    item: 'item 2',
    qty: 3,
    unitPrice: 30,
    totalAmount: qty*price,
   }
];
```

I want to calculate the value `totalAmount = qty * price`. How do I do that for the whole list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map()` and return the new object with all the previous properties and new property `totalAmount`

```js
let arr = [ { id: 1, item: 'item 1', qty: 23, unitPrice: 10 }, { id: 2, item: 'item 2', qty: 3, unitPrice: 30, } ];

let res = arr.map(x => ({...x, totalAmout:x.unitPrice * x.qty}));

console.log(res)
```